# An easy way to manually comment web_add_cookies in Vugen LR-Monotonous

Tags: performance, comments, load-testing, loadrunner

Can anyone recommend an easy way to comment `web_add_cookies` in the `Vugen` scripts? 
It's really monotonous doing manually with "`//`" for multiple `web_add_cookie` lines.
I tried with find & replace (Ctrl+H) but it disables only the first line.
I need the full `web_add_cookie` para to be disabled in one short command like Ctrl+H.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Ramanan

Answer (score 0):

Just search for "web_add_cookie" by using ctrl + H and replace it with //web_add_cookie (don't forget to do replace all).